# How to minify HTML output in Zend Framework 1.12

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, minify, google-pagespeed

As per the process mentioned here https://www.tkcodez.info/minify-html-output-via-php-code/. I have tried to inject one script in one of my layout files like this:

```
// Layout.phtml

<?php
function sanitize_output($buffer) {
    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',  // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
        '/(\s)+/s'       // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
    );
    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    );
    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
ob_start("sanitize_output");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<?php /*?><meta name="verify-v1" content="zXRjEY50qXN7Oxbt0tAIDegKmUk5nG32qLmAzMuZSw0=" /><?php */?>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="J-w0iienSxG8y23RN-NYZ0oh4y9YBygvb-ealpBmBi0" />

<?php
$controllerName = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$actionName = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getActionName();

$popupsessionTutor = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Popup_Session_Tutor');
$popupsessionCenter = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Popup_Session_Center');

?>

---- rest of the phtml file -----
```

But could not find my html view source minified. What else I need to do?

Comment: Asking the community to find libraries should not be done here on Stack Overflow. Read more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Ok...I have edited my question. Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using ZF1 and assuming MVC and what you've posted is a view script, you could write a controller plugin that defines a `dispatchLoopShutdown` method which does the response modification you want.

```
<?php
class My_Controller_Plugin_Sanitize extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopShutdown()
    {
        $search = array(
            '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
            '/[^\S ]+\</s',  // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
            '/(\s)+/s'       // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
        );
        $replace = array(
            '>',
            '<',
            '\\1'
        );
        $body = preg_replace($search, $replace, $this->getResponse()->getBody());

        $this->getResponse()->setBody($body);

        unset($body);
    }
}
```